# Setter works in Main function but no where else

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm having difficulty using my setters in another Class. But when I copy the same code to my Main class it works.

```
public class NewCharacter {

    CharacterInfo newChar = new CharacterInfo();

    newChar.setName("Name");

    String name = newChar.getName();
}
```

This code gives me the error "Cannot resolve symbol". But when I copy and paste this exact same code into my main function it works no problem. What I find odd is that the getter function works in both cases, it is only the setter that isn't working.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CharacterInfo newChar = new CharacterInfo();

        newChar.setName("Name");

        String name = newChar.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call methods directly in a class declaration - you can't do that. All you can do directly within a class is declare things - variables, methods, constructors and nested classes. Put your code in a method and it'll be fine. The reason the getter is deemed okay is that you're declaring a variable - if you just tried to call `getName()` without declaring a variable, that would fail too.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Super fast reply and bang on. I threw it in a method and it was fine! Thank you.